# SceneKit: How to get an image of SCNNode's current appearance?

Tags: swift, scenekit, arkit

I have a SCNNode that I need to do some custom modification to its appearance that can only be done on a CGImage due to resource constraints.

In buttonPressed, I want to be able to do something like

```
let snapshotImage: CGImage = node.imageOfCurrentAppearance

doSomeModification(inputCGImage: snapshotImage)
```

How can I go about getting an image of the SCNNode's current appearance? (almost like a screenshot of the node?)

Answer (score 0):

Make a separate SCNView with only the node added that you want to screenshot and use [snapshot()](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnview/1524031-snapshot) on your SCNView instance.